# Scrapy crawl spider returns broken urls

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to create a simple crawl spider, but the response.url seem to be broken.

The code i am currently running is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from teatrorecur.items import TeatrorecurItem

class Teatrorecurspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "teatrorecurspider"
    allowed_domains = ["cartelera.com.uy"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?,,PELICULAS,OBRA,0,26',
    )

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('CINE&OBRA&-1&29', )), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//a[@href="CINE%2COBRA%2C-1%2C29"]'), follow=False, callback='parse_item'),
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('CINE&OBRA&-1&29$', )), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
    )



    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = TeatrorecurItem()
        item['url']=response.url
        yield item
```

a sample url i'm getting from this code is

```
<200 http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?-1=&12415=&29=&CINE=&OBRA=>
```

but the corresponding element in the page has the following href value

```
<a href="http://www.cartelera.com.uy/apeliculafunciones.aspx?12415&&CINE&OBRA&-1&29">
```

as you can see, the string following the .aspx? is messed up, i have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkExtractor has a option named canonicalize that defaults to True.

Set it to False like so:

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('CINE&OBRA&-1&29',), canonicalize=False), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
)
```

This will prevent LinkExtractor from performing changes to the url described at the def of [canonicalize_url](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/url.py).